# Error "Property does not exist on type never[]"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, properties, typescript-never

Theres some questions about the same error here but i tried a few solutions that didnt end up working for me so i will try asking showing my situation, heres my code:

```
const[ enquetes, setEnquetes ] = useState([])

api.get('/polls/b44a0040-5201-4f0e-ba68-2b51545d5276').then( (response) => {
    setEnquetes(response.data)
    console.log(enquetes.title)
})
```

So im integrating a node server with a react typescript app. In the code above i got the informations from the server and stored in "enquetes" using useState. When i try to console.log(enquetes) it works fine, but when i try using "title" that is an existing property in the server or any other property, i get the error "Property does not exist on type never[]".
I already tried: useState<any[]>([]) in the const; console.log(enquetes['title'] and some other things but none worked, anyone can spot what should be done?

Heres the response.data, using console.log(enquetes):[image]

Comment: What's the shape of the data in `response.data`?

Comment: edited with the return from console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const[ enquetes, setEnquetes ] = useState([])
```

You havn't specified what type this state is, so typescript has to try to infer it. You passed in an array with no contents, so the best typescript can do is infer a `never[]`. Arrays do not have a `.title` property, so `enquentes.title` is not allowed.

`useState` is a generic, and you can pass in what type you want the state to be. I'd recommend you use something like `null` to represent the fact that you're still loading instead of an array, since it's easier to check for null. For example:

```
type Data {
  poll: {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    options: unknown[]; // fill this in with an appropriate type. I can't tell from your post.
  }
}

// ...
const [enquentes, setEnquentes] = useState<Data | null>(null);

// ...
api.get('/polls/b44a0040-5201-4f0e-ba68-2b51545d5276').then( (response) => {
    setEnquetes(response.data)
    console.log(response.data.poll.title)
    // there is no point in logging `enquentes` here, since it is null
})
```

When you want to use `enquentes`, do so something like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    {enquentes ? (
      <span>{enquentes.poll.title}</span>
    ) : (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    )}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Yes it did work now, thank you! I just dont understand why "enquetes" will be null at the console.log even with setEnquetes being called before? Shouldnt it store the value to the const?

Comment: the setter from `useState` is asynchronous, meaning the new value of `enquentes` is not available within that callback at that time. On the next render it would be

Comment: @Lucca `enquentes` is a local const. It cannot change. It contains a snapshot of what the state was when the component rendered. When you call `setEnquentes` this does not try to change your local const, instead it asks react to rerender the component. When it rerenders your component function will be called again, which will make a new local variable with a new snapshot, but code from the old render has no access to it.

Comment: @Derek `the setter from useState is asynchronous` That's true, but it's not the reason why it doesn't update. No matter how much time passes, the local variable will never be updated, since that's just a snapshot of what the state was at the time of rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possible answers to your problem.

**1. Object or Array**

In the declaration of the useState, the default value is an empty array, so I assume that the response from the get request from api should be also an array of objects.

If this is the case, the right way to display the property title from the response should be something like this:

```
                             console.log(enquetes[0].title)
```

Because an array is a collection of informations, can be an object like your case or a primitive like strings or numbers, and for you access this informations you need
specify the place you want, so that is why you put 0.

**2. Accessing your object wrong**

In the exemple of the response from the get, your object is poll: { id: string, title: string, options: array }.

For display the property title correctly you need acess the object poll before, like this:

```
                             console.log(enquetes.poll.title
```

I hope some of this answers help you.